# is there a way to guarantee that all properties of an interface are addressed

Tags: typescript

**STOP! IMPORTANT! READ FIRST:**

**i an NOT looking to solve the serialization problem below, i only used it as an example**

**the REAL QUESTION IS AT THE END, thank you**

UPDATE:

i am aware of an option to iterate through all properties using `Object.keys()`, however this is not what i am looking for, i am looking for a way to address  each property personally

UPDATE:

problem solved, check out my answer below

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

say i have an interface

```
interface Data { one: number; another: string; }
```

i have a serialization method

```
serialize(data: Data): string {
    return 'one: ' + data.one + ', another: ' + data.another;
}
```

now i am doing refactoring and want to add a new property to the `Data` interface, so that

```
interface Data { one: number; another: string; yetAnother: boolean; }
```

now by requirement the new property `yetAnother` must be serialized too, yet the compiler won't point out to that because i didn't ask for it, so there is a chance of a bug to slip in

**now my question**: is there a way to ask the TypeScript compiler if i addressed all properties of an interface?

crossposted to TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14947

Comment: I do not think that is possible, but why not just loop through the keys of `data` and make your `serialize` method generic so you don't face these issues?

Comment: Nope, no way to do that and I don't think that it's possible in any other language as well. In most languages you have some sort of a built-in serialization functionality, and in typescript/javascript you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which will always serialize all of the properties in the object you pass it. If you choose to serialize yourself then you'll need to maintain it yourself as well

Answer (score 0):

found an elegant solution thanks everyone (try it live at [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Around%3CT%2C%20R%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20(result%3A%20R%2C%20value%3A%20T%5BP%5D%2C%20name%3A%20P)%20%3D%3E%20R%3B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20around%3CT%2C%20R%3E(data%3A%20T%2C%20result%3A%20R%2C%20around%3A%20Around%3CT%2C%20R%3E)%3A%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20name%20in%20data)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20around%5Bname%5D(result%2C%20data%5Bname%5D%2C%20name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20identity%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%20return%20value%3B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20addOver%3CT%3E(toString%3A%20(value%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20add(values%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20value%3A%20T%2C%20name%3A%20string)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values.push(name%20%2B%20'%3A%20'%20%2B%20toString(value))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20values%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Data%20%7B%20one%3A%20number%2C%20another%3A%20string%2C%20yetAnother%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Afunction%20serialize(data%3A%20Data)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20return%20around%3CData%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E(data%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20one%3A%20addOver(String)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20another%3A%20addOver(identity)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yetAnother%3A%20addOver(String)%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D).join('%2C%20')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20serialized%20%3D%20serialize(%7B%20one%3A%201%2C%20another%3A%20'hey'%2C%20yetAnother%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aalert(serialized)%0D%0Aconsole.log(serialized))):

```
type Around<T, R> = { [P in keyof T]: (result: R, value: T[P], name: P) => R; }
function around<T, R>(data: T, result: R, around: Around<T, R>): R {
    for (const name in data) {
        result = around[name](result, data[name], name);
    }
    return result;/
}

function identity<T>(value: T): T { return value; }
function addOver<T>(toString: (value: T) => string) {
    return function add(values: string[], value: T, name: string): string[] {
         values.push(name + ': ' + toString(value));
         return values;
    };
}

interface Data { one: number, another: string, yetAnother: boolean }

function serialize(data: Data): string {
   return around<Data, string[]>(data, [], {
       one: addOver(String),
       another: addOver(identity),
       yetAnother: addOver(String)
   }).join(', ');
}

const serialized = serialize({ one: 1, another: 'hey', yetAnother: true });
alert(serialized) // one: 1, another: hey, yetAnother: true
```

Answer (score -1):

With my knowledge about TypeScript I'd say it's not possible. But what you're doing looks like you want to simply do

```js
interface Data { one: number; another: string; yetAnother: boolean; }

function serialize(data: Data): string {
  let result = '';
  
  Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      result += `${k}: ${data[k]}`;
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}
```

Since your interface does not mark these properties as optional (`one?: number`, note the question mark) it won't be possible to call the function if anything is missing (obviously, if not cast to `any` or something alike).

Comment: I would use `map` and `join` though -- takes care of the commas: `return Object.keys(data).map(x => \`${x}: ${data[x]}\`).join(",")`